# how to add multi custom vertical line in chart js using annotation

Tags: react-chartjs, chartjs-2.6.0

I added annotation for adding custom multiple vertical lines in my chart, if I add statically it working fine 
my static code:

```
annotation: {
        annotations: [
          {
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'vertical',
            scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
            value: 0.019,
            borderColor: 'rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.5)',
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
          {
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'vertical',
            scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
            value: 0.033,
            borderColor: 'rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.5)',
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
          {
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'vertical',
            scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
            value: 0.305,
            borderColor: 'rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.5)',
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
```

this code is working fine in my chart js i want to change the code in dynamice way so that i modified the code like this.

```
const testValue = ['0.019', '0.033', '0.305', '0.428', '0.582', '0.826'];
    const annotations = map(testValue, el => ({
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'vertical',
      scaleID: 'x-axis-label',
      value: el,
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderWidth: 1,
    }));
```

but this not displaying the line in my chart can any one tell me what is the problem in my code. 
Note: this chart is implemented in react js I am using this npm `react-chartjs-2` only for displaying the chart my version is also up to date only.

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ any solution for this

Answer (score 3):

I got the annotations plugin up and running. Please ensure you are using the latest versions of the packages:

```
chart.js: 2.7.3
chartjs-plugin-annotation: 0.5.7
react-chartjs-2: 2.7.4
```

When using chart.js version 2.7.2 it did not work (no error in console, but no line drawn/visible in the chart).

As pointed out in earlier posts, you should also import the chartjs-plugin-annotation:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as chartjs from 'chart.js';
import { Bar, ChartData, LinearComponentProps } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
```

Then you can add the annotation to the chart options object (for available configuration options, see https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation)

Comment: I have a similar problem to the one you indicated, I'm using the latest versions, but I don't understand what the problem is.
Online on codesanbox works fine but inside the project it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, the problem is `parseFloat(el)` i am not passing the value as an integer and i changed the `annotations` to `annotationsArr`

```
const testValue = ['0.019', '0.033', '0.305', '0.428', '0.582', '0.826'];
    const annotationsArr = map(testValue, el => {
      return {
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'vertical',
        scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
        value: parseFloat(el),
        borderColor: 'rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.5)',
        borderWidth: 1,
      }
    });
```

now it working fine for me

Comment: Can you post your react code?  I'm having issues getting annotations to render.